# Express.js, what does require return and why do we need to access the variable as a function to get its value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireid

> require(id)# Added in: v0.1.13 id  module name or path
> Returns:  exported module content

What does "module content" mean?

```
const x = require('express');
const y = x();
```

What is getting stored in `x()`?
Why do we need to access `x` as a function and store it in `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Express` exports a function, and in order to use it, you should call that function. To have a better image of what's happening, say you have these files:

`function.js`:

```js
const foo = () => console.log("Hello Word");
module.exports = foo;
```

`index.js`:

```js
const x = require('./function');
// x == foo
x(); // will log Hello Word
```

And if you hadn't had that `module.exports = foo` in `function.js`, `x` would be equal to `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

`require(id)` is the CommonJS syntax for importing modules whether that's via their npm package name or a path to a js/json file. When the function is called with a package name like `"express"`. That package is looked up in the `node_modules` directory and it tries to find an entrypoint in the `node_modules/express/package.json` file *or* if a `main` file isn't specified (as in the case of express) [`node_modules/express/index.js`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/index.js) can be used.

Following the imports from `index.js` lead you yo [`lib/express.js`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js) where the main exported function can be found:

```js
/**
 * Expose `createApplication()`.
 */

exports = module.exports = createApplication;

/**
 * Create an express application.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

as you can see in the code snippet above `x` is express' `createApplication` function since it's assigned to the `export` variable. As to why you need to call the `x` function, that's simply express' chosen way to instantiate their application, other packages do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

A [module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) is a bundle of related code.

[Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) is a module.

Modules can export values (much like object properties have values).

The exported values can be any type of value.

Functions are a type of value.

The value exported by Express is a function.

You can tell because [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) tells you to call it as a function and also by [looking at the source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L28).